# Responsive web design : "How to resize a background image according to browser window size using CSS"?

Tags: html, css, background-image, responsive-design, browser-width

I am creating a site where my all products images will be re-size according to browser window size so **i wrote some media queries where i used one big image and re-sized it in different window size but** i have one image which i used in background , how i can re-size it? I want support it  in all browser also in IE7 and 8.

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{ 
background: url("http://canadianneighborpharmacy.net/images/cnp/discount_20.png") 
no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
position:absolute;
width:45px; 
height: 45px; }
```

My live code is here :- http://jsfiddle.net/jamna/DdxbQ/19/ here i have a main "product image" which is now resizing according to browser window  size(in my fiddle i didn't write code for resizing product image yet,i am only showing which image i want to resize now ) but i have a another "save-money label" image which is in background of a "span" i want to re-size simultaneously with product image.

Answer (score 21):

for this you can use `background-size` property

Like :

```
body{
background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
}
```

there other properties like `contain` & `100% 100%`

check this link http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

for IE you can use `filter`

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

**EDIT:**
you live code is right but you have you define width & height in percentage like this

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/ayUKz/3/

& you can use `img` tag also like this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/RMGnM/

```
img{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height: 100%}
```

**EDIT:**

may be that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/DdxbQ/20/

check this link also http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-flexible.html

Comment: I want support it in all browser in IE7 and 8 too

Comment: @jitendra; it's support all browser accept IE for IE you can use filter

Comment: Just a small note: I noticed that Google Chrome has issues when using the `background-size: cover` attribute: It makes scrolling very jumpy. When using a jQuery plugin (for instance http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/) this problem dissapears and scrolling is smooth again.

Comment: @andrej; there no issue in chrome for using background-cover property check this link http://ringvemedia.com/ they use background-cover property

Comment: @sandeep thx for link i saw it , it is really nice ...sorry if you didn't get me right ..i have a div and there is a image i want both realizable simultaneously, according to browser width or size  see here http://jsfiddle.net/jamna/DdxbQ/19/

Comment: @sandeep: Well i did have issues that scrolling was jumpy when using a real big and high quality background images (talking about ~2200x1700px).Probably the problem lies somewhere else, but from what I can see on the web, I am not the only one having issues (see http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1242c84a137fda30&hl=en). Also, i dont think the website you linked does really use the background method described on css-tricks. (i see they have background images in a table at the bottom of the site and not in the css and they also use a js script to make it cover).

Comment: @sandeep can you please tell me where i am going wrong in my this example http://jsfiddle.net/jamna/3Zs2u/22/ because when browser window size reach at 1025 "save-money label" image is not resizing smoothly it's directly showing in its max-width