# Resizing Background image for mobile device

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

Right then, I've just been playing with my site, and adding a "new" banner onto some of the images, I've done this the simplest way I could think which is as follows..

```
<img style="background:url(images/pic3.jpg)" src="images/new.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Now this works fine when viewed on a desktop as the images are already the right size for the site, but when I view it on a mobile device the .png image  is scaled down, but not the background image..

I know I'm missing something from the css, but as I'm still learning, I don't know exactly what its missing, which is where you guys come in..

here is a little more of my html..

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
        <img style="background:url(images/pic3.jpg)" src="images/new.png" alt="" />
             </a>
                 </div>
```

And here is the mobile css in question..

```
.thumbnails
{
}

    .thumbnails .thumbnail
    {
        border-top: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
        padding-top: 2em;
        margin-top: 2em;
    }

    .thumbnails .first
    {
        border-top: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .thumbnails .thumbnail img
        {
            margin-top: 5px;
            height: 180px;
            margin-right: 8px;
        }

    .thumbnails .thumbnail blockquote
        {

            margin-left: 143px;
        }
```

So basically, I just need to know, how to make the background image scale down like the foreground image (the .png image)

I'm sure someone can help, so many thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is a quick fiddle, so you can see whats going on... http://jsfiddle.net/bBMdp/

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660931/responsive-web-deisgn-how-to-resize-a-background-image-according-to-browser-w

Comment: Apologies if it is, but I don't understand the question or answer to the above question, so needed to ask myself..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
.thumbnails .thumbnail img{
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-right: 8px;

    background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

Or:

```
.thumbnails .thumbnail img{
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-right: 8px;

    background-size: cover;

}
```

**Source(s)**

[MDN - background-size - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size)

Comment: This Doesn't seem to make any difference.. thanks for answer though.

Comment: Try background-size: cover?

Comment: afraid not, still nothing.. I've made a fiddle so you can see whats going on.. http://jsfiddle.net/bBMdp/

Comment: Ahh, the inline `background` property was overruling the `background-size` property. I simply added `!important` and it worked! http://jsfiddle.net/bBMdp/1/

Comment: You sir, are a star! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size:XXpx XXpx;` first value is take width and second value is take height.

Comment: and this is to be placed in the " .thumbnails .thumbnail img{ " section yeah? as above, this doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-background-style: cover;
-moz-background-style: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-style: cover;
```

This will scale down the background so it's only ever big enough to cover the whole box.

Comment: As above, thanks for the answer, but nothing seems to be making a difference at the moment.